# $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$ given by $f(t) = (t^2,t^3)$ is an immersion at $0$.

Tags: differential-geometry, proof-verification, manifolds, differential-topology

$(a)$ Let $\sigma :\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be $\sigma(t) = t^2$. Is $(\sigma , \Bbb R)$ a coordinate chart on $\Bbb R$?

$(b)$ Let $\phi :\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be $\phi(t) = t^3$. Does this gives a smooth manifold structure on $\Bbb R$?

$(c)$ Determine if the function $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^2$ given by $f(t) = (t^2,t^3)$ is an immersion at $0$.

---

$(a)$ $(\sigma , \Bbb R)$ is not a coordinate chart on $\Bbb R$ as it does not cover the -ve points.

$(b)$ It does not give a smooth manifold structure on $\Bbb R$, as $t \to t^3$ is  a homeomorphism but it is not a diffeomorphism, as its inverse $x\mapsto x^{\frac 13}$ is not smooth.

$(c)$ $f$ is an immersion if $\forall p\in\mathbb{R}$, $df_p$ is injective. I have computed $Df_p=(2t,3t^2)$ . I have an intuition $df_p$ is injective at $0$.

Please verify the solution, and need help for part $(c)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (a), you can argue that $\sigma$ is not injective, also. Your reasoning is correct, though.

In (b), for the atlas ${\cal A} = \{(\Bbb R, \phi)\}$, the only coordinate change is the identity map, which is differentiable, so ${\cal A}$ is contained in a maximal atlas, and the answer is *yes*. If you have not yet fixed differentiable strucutres in $\Bbb R$, it does not makes sense to ask if $\phi$ is differentiable. When you write $\phi:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R$, the first $\Bbb R$ is the topological manifold you're trying to endow with a differentiable structure, and the second $\Bbb R$ is the "model" of the chart.

For (c), since $f'(0)=(0,0)$, the derivative $df_{0}:T_0\Bbb R\to T_{(0,0)}\Bbb R^2$ is the zero map, hence $f$ is not an immersion.

Comment: it might be helpful to point out that what @userly0 's argument proves is that the standard differential structure is not diffeomorphic to the differential structure determined by $t^3$.

Comment: I am having difficulty in understanding solution of b.

Comment: An atlas ${\cal A}$ in a topological manifold is smooth if given $(U,\phi),(V,\psi)\in  {\cal A}$, then $$\psi\circ\phi^{-1}:\phi(U\cap V)\to \psi(U\cap V)$$ is differentiable ($C^\infty$) as a map between open sets of Euclidean spaces. A differentiable structure is a maximal atlas, and every atlas is contained in a differentiable structure. It is a matter of understanding definitions, only.

Comment: @ArturAraujo The atlas defined by the map $t\mapsto t^3$ gives $\mathbb{R}$ a different smooth structure, but this is diffeomorphic to the standard one. Actually any two smooth structures on $\mathbb{R}^n$ are diffeomorphic if $n\neq 4.$

Comment: The map $$\phi:(\Bbb R, \mathcal{A}_\phi)\to (\Bbb R,\mathcal{A}_{\rm can})$$ is a diffeomorphism. It is smooth because it has local expression ${\rm Id}_{\Bbb R}\circ \phi \circ \phi^{-1} = {\rm Id}_{\Bbb R}$. And similarly, the inverse $$\phi^{-1}:(\Bbb R,\mathcal{A}_{\rm can})\to (\Bbb R,\mathcal{A}_\phi)$$ is smooth because of the local expression $\phi\circ \phi^{-1}\circ {\rm Id}_{\Bbb R}^{-1}={\rm Id}_{\Bbb R}$. Here, $\mathcal{A}_{\rm can}$ and $\mathcal{A}_\phi$ denote, respectively, the smooth structures containing the charts $(\Bbb R, {\rm Id}_{\Bbb R})$ and $(\Bbb R,\phi)$.

Comment: In general, if $M$ is a smooth manifold and $(U,\phi)$ is a chart, then the open set $U$ is a smooth manifold on its own right, and the smooth structure in question makes $\phi:U\to \phi(U)$ a diffeomorphism (here we consider the canonical smooth structure in the open set $\phi(U)$ induced by the canonical  smooth structure in $\Bbb R^{\dim M} $).

Comment: @positrón0802 sorry, i meant not diffeomorphic through the identity map. You are of course right. I thought it would be helpful to explain where the poster's reasoning went wrong on b.